# NSTimer: How to change the scheduled method without having delay?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone  **TIMER** app,

after some interval of time I need to change the scheduled method t....

```
-(void)startTimerAction
{
    NSLog(@"Start timer Action");
    NSLog(@"Time is Over %@",isTimeOver?@"YES":@"NO");

    if(!isTimeOver)
    {
    timer_main = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(ShowActicity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    else if(isTimeOver)
    {
    timer_main = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) target:self selector:@selector(continueClock) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];    
    }

}
```

So, to stop and reschedule it I am doing this...in some method..

```
isTimeOver=YES;
               [timer_main invalidate];
               timer_main=nil;
               [self startTimerAction];
```

for doing this there is some time delay or unwanted interval to reschedule the timer in a new method....

How can I do it smoothly.....

I just want to reschedule the timer with another method without having delay.....

Right Now I am doing this to fix it.....

```
      NSTimeInterval x=[[timer_main fireDate] timeIntervalSinceNow];
       [timer_main invalidate];
       timer_main=nil;
       sleep(x);   
       totalCount++; 
       seconds++;
       if(seconds>59)
       {
           minutes++;
           seconds=0;
       }

       [self startTimerAction];
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You can [schedule repeating timers with a firedate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW4):

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:fireDate
                                  interval:interval
                                  target:self
                                  selector:@selector(foo)
                                  userInfo:nil
                                  repeats:YES];
NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: ... and then in foo, check your isTimerOver flag.